# No successful migration from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 yet

Tags: migrations

The upgrade reaches the following point:
Currently upgrading Node type configuration (40 of 70 total tasks)

then it fails with the following message:
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /drupal/batch?id=3&op=do_nojs&op=do
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: 
Welcome to drupal8testlocale 
...
Create new accountReset your password

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check the Case Study https://www.drupal.org/node/2657338 . It have been successfully migrated from drupal 7 to drupal 8 with the official migration tools.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The question as it is, it is a polling ("has anyone managed to..."), to which the answer is just pointing out who successfully did a migration to Drupal 8. If you have a specific question, ask that.